# Print all Mail in BSD:Mail

Tags: macos

I've set up a hourly cronjob recently on OSX, and I now constantly get messages saying "You have new mail".

My current flow for seeing everything:

```
mail
<hit enter to display first message>
<hit q to return to index>
<loop back to step 2 until I have no more mail>
quit
```

which seems unnecessarily burdensome.

What I'd like to do:

```
mail --print-all
```

and have it simply print all mail to the terminal, and then delete them or mark them as read.

But thus far, I haven't been able to figure out how to print out the mail contents to terminal, and bypass having to use the mail interactive application.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling, I've given up on trying to find an answer to this using the mail application. My new flow is to create an alias that does the following

```
gsed '/From username/,+16 d' < /var/mail/username && cp /dev/null /var/mail/username
```

Ie, it bypasses the mail app and parses the mail-file directly. It also clears all content in the mail file at the end, so that you'll stop getting the mail-notification messages, after having read them. If you just want to print all mail headers/content, a simple cat would do. I'm using the gsed command so that all headers will be deleted and only the message-contents will be printed to stdout.

Note that the above is only a workaround. The true answer to the question seems to be that *"No, the functionality requested doesn't exist"*.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat /var/mail/yourusername | less
```

and then tap the spacebar to see more.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: I agree with Joel. I like the fact that the output is being mailed to me. I just want to be able to view it directly from the cmd-line

Comment: Sorry I misread your question.. I was thinking you did not want to see them.

Comment: what about  cat /var/log/mail/yourusername | less and then you can  tap the spacebar to see more.